# Can't create a hangoutsMeet with calendar API using Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

here is the code.

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    InputStream in = ModuloCalendar.class.getResourceAsStream("quickstart-1585944958709-f0acf97c5fa8.json");  

    Collection<String> scopes  = CalendarScopes.all();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in).createScopes(scopes);
    return credential;
}
```

```
Calendar entry = new Calendar();
entry.setSummary(descripcion);

ConferenceProperties conferenceProperties=new ConferenceProperties();

List<String> allowedConferenceSolutionTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

allowedConferenceSolutionTypes.add("hangoutsMeet");

conferenceProperties.setAllowedConferenceSolutionTypes(allowedConferenceSolutionTypes);

entry.setConferenceProperties(conferenceProperties);
View.display(entry);

Calendar result = client.calendars().insert(entry).execute();
View.display(result);
```

I have done steps on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

it create the calendar, but it's always return 
`"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes":["eventHangout"]`

Not `hangoutsMeet`

Comment: What steps from the link you provided are you talking about? It seems completely irrelevant to your code.

Comment: Hi. Create a Servirce Account and Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account (here is more about https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth) . This are required before use the client API . 

Credential credential = ModuloCalendarSalud.authorize();
client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
         httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential  ).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Comment: Can I ask; what are you trying to accomplish here? The only reason you need to delegate domain-wide authority to a service account it if you want to execute a task as another user on your domain. Without a full picture of what you are trying to do I am unable to understand about your situation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Rafa I want to create  Calendar 's Event (using Calendar API)  with a conference (hangoutMeet) using my  domain. I can create a Calendar Event (but with  hangout, not meet).

Comment: `Calendars: insert` doesn't create an event, it creates an entire calendar. Are you sure this is what you need to do? See the difference between [`Calendars: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) and [`Events: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).

Comment: That said, I have tried creating a calendar using the 'Try this API' feature of the aforementioned `Calendars: insert` page and I got a return of `hangoutsMeet` with no issue. Can you please confirm if this is the same for you? (The Try this API feature can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)).

Comment: Hi Guillermo... yes to both... first a i create a calendar (that is the code  passed before), but the calendar "insert" returns "conferenceProperties":{"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes":["eventHangout"]} ... of course then i tried to create an event with "hangoutsMeet", but it falil without error.  ..... second: i "try  this API" using the page, with Google OAuth 2.0 and it's return only hangoutMeet. It'is Ok.  My problem is in the server side using Java (It is only working for hangout, not for hangoutMeet)

Comment: Just to check; are you doing this logged in as a G Suite domain user, or an `@gmail.com` account?

Comment: i am doing it, with a service account  see authorize(). and i grant  this service account in a GSuite Domian.

Comment: Okay, I see.  And finally to be clear, are you sure you're vreating the calendar on behalf of a user, and not as the service account itself? Are you able to view the calendar when you go to [https://calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com)?

Comment: Now, I am creating the calendar in the service account itself.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*As Service accounts are not part of your domain, they can not create calendars that they own with a `conferenceSolution` of `hangoutsMeet`.*

#### More Information:

It took me a little while to understand this but, as per the documentation for the [`Events` resource of the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events), the conference solution types are as follows:

> - `"eventHangout"`: for Hangouts for consumers (http://hangouts.google.com)
> - `"eventNamedHangout"`: for classic Hangouts ***for G Suite users*** (http://hangouts.google.com)
> - `"hangoutsMeet"`: for Hangouts Meet (http://meet.google.com)
> - `"addOn"`: for 3P conference providers

And from the [Google Cloud Service Account documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts):

> Service accounts are **not** members of your G Suite domain, unlike user accounts. For example, if you share assets with all members in your G Suite domain, they will not be shared with service accounts. Similarly, any assets created by a service account cannot be owned or managed by G Suite admins.

What you're experiencing is a result of this: a Service Account is not part of your domain, and therefore can not create a calendar ***for itself*** that has the `hangoutsMeet` value for the Conference Solution Type.

If you wish the Calendar to have this conference solution type, you must create the calendar such that it is owned by a member of your G Suite domain; that is to say, **have the service account create a calendar impersonating as a member of your G Suite domain.**

The reason you are getting the correct result from the `Try this API` feature of `Calendars: insert` is because the API call is being authorised as you - a G Suite domain user.

#### Building the Service Account credentials:

When you're doing your authentication you need to set the user that you wish to impersonate before building:

```java
GoogleCredential.Builder b = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
 .setTransport(httpTransport)
 .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory)
 .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
 .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(yourPrivateKey)
 .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
 //the user whom you want to impersonate here:
 .setServiceAccountUser(email-to-impersonate);

credential = b.build();

return credential;
```

Or with pk12 file:

```java
GoogleCredential.Builder b = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
 .setTransport(httpTransport)
 .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
 .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
 .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(pk12)
 .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
 //the user whom you want to impersonate here:
 .setServiceAccountUser(email-to-impersonate);

credential = b.build();

return credential;
```

#### References:

- [`Calendars: insert` | Google Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)
- [Events | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [Understanding service accounts | Cloud IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
- [Service accounts | Cloud IAM Documentation | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)

Comment: Yes Guillermo. Thanks. But, how can i do that " create the calendar such that it is owned by a member of your G Suite domain..." ?

Comment: If you get a p12 file for your credentials rather than the JSON it is easier. I have updated my code to show you how this is done.